# Angular 6 and component.css

Tags: css, angular, angular6

In the "latest" Angular 6:

For some reason the styles I define in the `component.css` file do not apply.

I believe this was working before in earlier versions of angular, and there must be a reason for having that file there in the first place?

I have Googled it and I found that you can set `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native` in the component declaration, but then the global CSS is ignored.

Anyone who can explain why? Eventually how to do this correctly?

Comment: Is component.css the root css which you have provided styles?

Answer (score 0):

> For Explaining why your solution of setting encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native doesn't work

The reason is you told angular to make a shadow root of your component and apply only the css that is local to it. That means the style specified inside the component with `style` or `styleUrl` will only apply to it.

> And for how to do it correctly is...

If your wish is to make a component work with both the styles which provided globally as well as styles provided locally is to

**1. Place all your styling rules to the style.css located at the root of your project directory. This will apply to all the component globally**

**2. While dealing with the CSS file of the component itself make sure you prepend `./` like this `styleUrl: ./component.css`**

I would encourage you to go through these resources to have a better knowledge

https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/06/29/shadow-dom-strategies-in-angular2.html

https://angular.io/guide/component-styles